# golang's handling of localhost

Tags: go, dns, resolve, musl

I have an alpine linux system which uses the musl libc and therefore has no `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

According to tcpdump on this system, `net.LookupIP("localhost")` actually does a query for `localhost.a.b.c`, where `a.b.c` is taken from `domain a.b.c` in `/etc/resolv.conf`.  But if I add an `/etc/nsswitch.conf` with `hosts: files dns`, it correctly looks up `localhost` from `/etc/hosts`.

As far as I can tell, no libc implementation tries to add a domain to `localhost` when looking it up in DNS.  So (a) is there some good reason it's done this way or is it a bug?  and (b) is there a way to work around it without adding an nsswitch.conf and while still using just the name `localhost`?

***Edit*** More details:

```
ldd ./dnstest
    /lib/ld-musl-armhf.so.1 (0x76f2c000)
    libc.so => /lib/ld-musl-armhf.so.1 (0x76f2c000)
```

So yes, there is a dependency on `libc.so`.  I have tried this with `CGO_ENABLED=1` and with `CGO_ENABLED=0` in the build commandline, too.

Comment: Is it _fully static_ build or not? IOW, does running `ldd ./that_binary` displays dependency on some `libc`?

Comment: I'm asking because by default the `net` package uses `libc` for name resolution; in fully static builds, a custom stub code is used. See [this](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#hdr-Name_Resolution) and [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=golang+cgo+resolver) in general.

Comment: Plus the go resolver will read resolv.conf and nsswitch.conf, as long as they don't specify any features that require the system resolver.

Comment: @kostix I've added some detail to the question.

Comment: If the binary is linked to libc, and this happens both with and without CGO regardless of `GODEBUG=netdns` settings, then it appears that both resolvers act identically. Without `hosts: files` in nsswitch, a linux system resolver is not going to read `/etc/hosts` first, which is where `localhost` is defined.

Comment: @JimB as far as I can tell, that's only true for GNU libc systems - other libc implementations don't use nsswitch.conf.

Comment: Even if it's only glibc, Go following the behavior of the most common resolver wouldn't be surprising, especially since that implementation was partly a concession to match existing system behaviors to begin with. Though it appears from your description here the musl resolver does the same?

Comment: After reading [this](https://wiki.musl-libc.org/functional-differences-from-glibc.html#Name-Resolver/DNS) I wonder what's the value of your `ndots` conf. variable?

Comment: @kostix ndots is not set in my resolv.conf.  I think it defaults to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- alpine think that it's golang bug:
  https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/367
- golang think
  it's not be compatible with glibc:
  https://github.com/golang/go/issues/35305
- golang is waiting changes of glibc: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/33019
- maybe glibc is making
  change: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=28700

So currently, it still needs `RUN [ ! -e /etc/nsswitch.conf ] && echo 'hosts: files dns' > /etc/nsswitch.conf` as workaround to use alpine image as base image to run golang binary.